# Beginner Help: Creating and Storing Text Using PHP

Tags: php, html, fopen, fputs

I'm trying to write a program where the basic idea is I ask the user for input in a textarea, and then the text gets stored into a word file. Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Guestbook</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Simple Guestbook Comment Creator</h1>
<br>
<form method = "post"
        action = "mysite.php">
    <textarea name = "text"
        rows = "10"
        cols = "20">Write Here</textarea>

<input type = "submit"
        value = "Submit Comment">

</form>

<?
    if($_POST['text'] !== NULL){
        $comment = $_POST['text'];


    $file = fopen("texttest.txt", "a");
    fputs($file, "<br>\n$comment");
    fclose($file);  
    }       

?>

</body> 
</html>
```

I can't seem to get this to work properly. I was also thinking about somehow making the form action store the text and then reload the site, but I haven't gotten that to work (the original file is mysite.php, so the action is to just reload the page).

If anyone has any better ideas of an algorithm to use/different syntax to use, please let me know, as I just started learning basic PHP syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work.

You might want to do more with the values they are entering and all, but this will basically do what you are asking.

You will also want to make sure that you have the correct path of the file you are trying to write to and that that file has the correct permissions to allow it to be written to:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Guestbook</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Simple Guestbook Comment Creator</h1><br>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (strlen(trim($_POST['comment']))) {
                $file = fopen("texttest.txt", "a");
                fputs($file, "$_POST['comment'])\n");
                fclose($file);  
            }
        } else {
    ?>
    <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">

        <label>Leave your comment
        <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Comment" />

    </form>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Also, since you are returning to the same page you may want to put some kind of message letting the person know that they succeeded in entering something into your address book.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What does strlen(trim($_POST['comment'])) do (in particular how does this return a boolean, or does it)? Also is there an advantage to using $_SERVER... rather than just putting in the .php filename again?

Comment: strlen returns and integer and before I get the length of `$_POST['comment']`, it is probably best to get rid of empty spaces on either end of the comment. then strlen will return the length of the comment. If the comment has any length (and thus strlen returns an integer greater than 0), the if statement will evaluate to true. Otherwise, it will return 0 and the if statement will evaluate to false and then the code to write to the file won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Does php have the permission to write files in that directory?
2. Is that php file called "myfile.php"?

Anyway, when something does not work and you want to know what's causing the arror, place `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your php - it will output any error or warning, including the ones trown by fopen().

Also, you might want to check whether the variable has been correctly submitted: `echo $comment` right after you assign it.

Comment: When I load the webpage, it tells me "Notice: Undefined index: text in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.php on line 21".

Comment: It means there is no element called "text" in the post array. (in php there is a difference between "unset" and "null"). You should change line 21 in `if(isset($_POST['text']))`